# How to get to the redirected page using Request and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, request, jsdom

I am using Request, Jsdom and NodeJS to log in to a webpage. According to the [Request api](https://github.com/request/request),

`followRedirect` - follow HTTP 3xx responses as redirects (default: `true`). This property can also be implemented as function which gets response object as a single argument and should return true if redirects should continue or false otherwise.

Given that this is defaulted to true, I would think that request would give me the redirected page, instead of the redirect page in the middle.

My code:

```
    request(loginPageURL, function(error, response, body) {
    /*Error handling removed for brevity*/
        jsdom.env({
            html: body,
            scripts: [
                'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'
            ],
            done: function(err, window) {
                //Set login fields  
                var form = $('#authorizationForm');
                var data = form.serialize();
                var url = form.attr('action') || 'get';
                var type = form.attr('enctype') || 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
                var method = form.attr('method');

                request({
                    url: url,
                    method: method.toUpperCase(),
                    body: data,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-type': type
                    }
                }, function(error, response, body) {
                    if (!error) {
                        console.log("Response.statusCode:" + response.statusCode);
                        console.log("Body:" + body);
```

Instead of giving me the home page after logging in, the output is:

```
Response.statusCode: 302
Body: To access this site, go to <a href="...">
```

While getting the code from the redirected page might be useful, how do I skip to the page that it is redirecting me to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a non-GET request? Then you need to explicitly set `followAllRedirects: true`.

> `followAllRedirects` - follow non-GET HTTP 3xx responses as redirects (default: `false`)

https://github.com/request/request

(The docs for `followRedirect` are confusing because they don't seem to indicate that `followRedirect` only applies to GETs.)

Comment: Thanks @Emmett! Due to the authentication/cookie setting, I also needed to set the request defualts on jars to true.